# Hangman game: How to find the word?

Tags: java

I have to create a hangman game. I am stuck in the last step. In fact, when the user finds the word my input asks yet a letter.

Here an example: (the word to find is "non")

**Enter your letter please** : n

```
n _ n
```

**Enter your letter please** : o

```
n o n
```

***Enter your letter please*** :

```
n o n
```

My problem is probably my `wordFind`, I don't understand how to manipulate this ?

```
        String[] words = {"yess", "non"};
        String wordRandom = words[(int) (Math.random() *  words.length)];
        boolean[] letterGuess = new boolean [wordRandom.length()];
        boolean wordFind = false;
        int numberAttempt = 5;

        while(numberAttempt > 0 && !wordFind){
           System.out.println("Number of attempt(s) " + numberAttempt);

           for(int i=0; i < wordRandom.length(); i++){

                if(letterGuess[i]){
                    System.out.print(wordRandom.charAt(i));
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("- ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.print("Enter your letter please : ");
            char letter = input.next().charAt(0);

            int letterFound = 0;
            boolean alreadyFound = false;


            for(int i=0; i < wordRandom.length(); i++){
                if(wordRandom.charAt(i) == letter){

                    if(letterGuess[i]){
                        alreadyFound  = true;
                    }

                letterGuess[i] = true;
                letterFound++;

                }

            }
                if(alreadyFound){

                    System.out.println("Letter already proposed and it has been found ! ");

                } else{
                    if(letterFound == 1){
                        System.out.println("The letter is correct ! ");
                    }

                    else if(letterFound  > 0){
                        System.out.println("The letter is " + letterFound  + " times in the word ! ");
                    }

                    else{
                        numberAttempt--;
                        System.out.println("The letter is not in the word ! ");
                    }



            }




        }
```

Comment: Stop if there are no more `false` elements in `letterGuess`. That should not be too hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable `int amountCorrect = 0;` and use that as a check. Every time the user gets a right letter, add to `amountCorrect` the number of letters there are. At the beginning of the `while` loop, create a boolean check that checks if the `amountCorrect` variable is the same as the length of the `wordRandom`. I know your code is kind of long, so I put a comment next to the lines where I added code:

```
    String[] words = { "yess", "non" };
    String wordRandom = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)];
    boolean[] letterGuess = new boolean[wordRandom.length()];
    boolean wordFind = false;
    int numberAttempt = 5;
    int amountCorrect = 0; // The amountCorrect variable

    while (numberAttempt > 0 && !wordFind) {
        System.out.println("Number of attempt(s) " + numberAttempt);

        // This is the boolean check
        if (amountCorrect == wordRandom.length()) {
            System.out.println("You Win!");
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wordRandom.length(); i++) {

            if (letterGuess[i]) {
                System.out.print(wordRandom.charAt(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print("- ");
            }

        }

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.print("Enter your letter please : ");
        char letter = input.next().charAt(0);

        int letterFound = 0;
        boolean alreadyFound = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < wordRandom.length(); i++) {
            if (wordRandom.charAt(i) == letter) {

                if (letterGuess[i]) {
                    alreadyFound = true;
                }

                letterGuess[i] = true;
                letterFound++;

                // add to amountCorrect
                amountCorrect++;

            }

        }
        if (alreadyFound) {

            System.out.println("Letter already proposed and it has been found ! ");

        } else {
            if (letterFound == 1) {
                System.out.println("The letter is correct ! ");
            }

            else if (letterFound > 0) {
                System.out.println("The letter is " + letterFound + " times in the word ! ");
            }

            else {
                numberAttempt--;
                System.out.println("The letter is not in the word ! ");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot TheXDShrimp. I understood ^^

Comment: Note that there's a bug in this as well as my answer: if you keep guessing a letter that you've already guessed, it will tell you that you've won.  To fix it, put the code after `if (letterGuess[i])` in an `else` block so that it isn't executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `solved` condition like this

```
    boolean wordFind = false;
    int numberAttempt = 5;
    boolean solved = false;

    while(numberAttempt > 0 && !wordFind && !solved){
```

after you update `letterFound`, set `solved`

```
letterFound++;
if (letterfound == wordRandom.length()) {
    solved = true
}
```

Then at the end after the while loop, if `solved` is true, congratulate the user.

Comment: Thank you for your help... I am trying but I always have the same probem. Is it my lines are corrects ? https://repl.it/repls/AlphanumericProudCosmos